# Socket.io Server Url For Testing

Tags: java, android, node.js, websocket, socket.io

in my Android app I have created a Socket.io client side(V2). My problem is that I couldnt any socket.io url which use v3 or higher.

For example these two url use socket.io under v3. ->

https://socketio-chat-h9jt.herokuapp.com/ or

https://socketio-whiteboard-zmx4.herokuapp.com/

Note: I dont know how to create server side. I am an new grad Android Developer. Thanks in advance.